# Why am I getting an Illegal invocation error from cordova media plugin?

Tags: cordova, media-player, cordova-media-plugin

This is the code I am running:

```
var clicker = new Media("sounds/click.wav", function(){ console.log("Playing Click"); }, console.log);
clicker.play();
```

I basically copied it from the documentation, so I assumed it would immediately work, however when I actually try and run it I get this error:

```
I/MediaFocusControl( 1486):  AudioFocus  requestAudioFocus() from android.media.AudioManager@21802acforg.apache.cordova.media.AudioHandler$1@3bb77c5c req=1flags=0x0
I/chromium( 3671): [INFO:CONSOLE(312)] "Error in Success callbackId: Media1544259360 : TypeError: Illegal invocation", source: file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js (312)
```

What causes this error? I've tried a variety of different success callback functions, and none of them worked, so I now suspect this maybe due to a misconfiguration somewhere entirely separate, but I have no idea how to track it down.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out there were two problems: The first, is that I needed to change the file path to `/android_asset/www/sounds/beep.mp3`. I had already tried that though, and dismissed it because it didn't work... which is due to the second problem: The cordova media plugin cannot play WAV files. After converting the file to mp3, it worked perfectly.

Leaving this up for the benefit of future visitors: The important takeaway is that

a) "illegal invocation" can mean "invalid or missing file"

b) media files must be in mp3 format, NOT wav.